# Is there a package that lets you use selectableDayPredicate for the showDateRangePicker in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm making kind of an Airbnb clone and I need a way for users to place a booking with simple UI without making booking conflicts.

So is there a way to do something like this?

```dart
showDateRangePicker(
   context: context,
   firstDate: DateTime.now(),
   lastDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 365)),
   selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime? selectedDate, DateTime date) => _isDateBooked(selectedDate, date),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just ended up using two `showDatePicker()`s.

I'll edit this answer if I find something more elegant.